# How to use bitcoin from command line in Windows?

Tags: windows

In Windows, how can I get what I get with "bitcoind getinfo" in Linux?

Answer (score 1):

If it's QT:
go to "Help" -> "Debug Window" -> "console"
type rpc command here

Or go from the commandline to the folder your bitcoin daemon is in and run a command from the bitcoin exe. NOTE: you may need to add server=1 to your bitcoin.conf in %APPDATA%

Comment: Where is the daemon? I can find only bitcoin-qt.exe

Comment: not sure what you are asking?

Comment: bitcoin-qt.exe is in the installation directory and bitcoind.exe is in the daemon subdirectory.

Comment: @ScripterRon : thanks. The question originally was just a block quote from my answer.

Answer (score 0):

For working `bitcoind` command in windows, you have to go to dir `C:\Program Files\Bitcoin\daemon` and Execute these commands. Using **Bitcoin core version 16** on windows 10.

> **bitcoind getinfo** in Linux
>
> **bitcoind -h** in windows

*Use this command after changing directory like shown in pic*

[image]