# How to use bitcoin from the command line in Windows?

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, command-line-options, cli

Do there exist any stable and audited bitcoin wallets that can be used from the cli on Windows? I have looked but have been unable to find any that I can use for automated tasks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `bitcoind` and `bitcoin-cli` in windows too. [See this post for more information.](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/20030/how-to-use-bitcoin-from-command-line-in-windows)